# QT5 Cannot get different custom context menus to work for different tables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5

I am trying to get multiple (3) custom context menus to work, each for a different table view.

My code works fine in debug but in release I am not getting the different context menus - the best I have managed to get is either the first menu working (and the others disabled) or displaced menus (i.e. the menu is offset relative to the top left corner of the screen not at the cursor).

The code:

```
void DisplayWidget::Init()
{
    // ParameterData Table
    pLabel_Param            = new QLabel(tr("PARAMETER DATABASE"));
    pTableW_Param           = new QTableWidget(this);
       
    // EmuNameIn Table
    pLabel_EmuNameIn        = new QLabel(tr("EMULATOR NAME IN"));
    pTableW_EmuNameIn       = new QTableWidget(this);
       
    // EmuNameOut Table
    pLabel_EmuNameOut       = new QLabel(tr("EMULATOR NAME OUT"));
    pTableW_EmuNameOut      = new QTableWidget(this);
    
    // Setup context menus
    pTableW_Param->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(pTableW_Param, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), SLOT(customMenuRequested_Param(QPoint)));
    
    pTableW_EmuNameIn->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(pTableW_EmuNameIn, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), SLOT(customMenuRequested_EmuNameIn(QPoint)));
    
    pTableW_EmuNameOut->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(pTableW_EmuNameOut, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), SLOT(customMenuRequested_EmuNameOut(QPoint)));
}


void DisplayWidget::customMenuRequested_Param(QPoint pos) 
{
    if(!pTableW_Param || (sizeOfTable_Param == 0)) return;

    QModelIndex index = pTableW_Param->indexAt(pos);

    QMenu *menuParam = new QMenu(this);
    if(IsEmuValid()) menuParam->addAction(pAct_AddParam);
    menuParam->addAction(pAct_SearchTable_Param);
    menuParam->popup(pTableW_Param->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}

void DisplayWidget::customMenuRequested_EmuNameIn(QPoint pos) 
{
    if(!pTableW_EmuNameIn || !IsEmuValid() || (sizeOfTable_EmuNameIn == 0)) return;

    QModelIndex index = pTableW_EmuNameIn->indexAt(pos);

    QMenu *menuNameIn = new QMenu(this);
    menuNameIn->addAction(pAct_DeleteFromNameIn);
    menuNameIn->addAction(pAct_Toggle_InToOut);
    menuNameIn->addAction(pAct_SearchTable_EmuNameIn);
    menuNameIn->addAction(pAct_SortTable_EmuNameIn);
    menuNameIn->popup(pTableW_EmuNameIn->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}

void DisplayWidget::customMenuRequested_EmuNameOut(QPoint pos) 
{
    if(!pTableW_EmuNameOut || !IsEmuValid() || (sizeOfTable_EmuNameOut == 0)) return;

    QModelIndex index = pTableW_EmuNameOut->indexAt(pos);

    QMenu *menuNameOut = new QMenu(this);
    menuNameOut->addAction(pAct_DeleteFromNameOut);
    menuNameOut->addAction(pAct_Toggle_OutToIn);
    menuNameOut->addAction(pAct_SearchTable_EmuNameOut);
    menuNameOut->addAction(pAct_SortTable_EmuNameOut);
    menuNameOut->popup(pTableW_EmuNameOut->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

I have tried looking / searching for the same problem, but failed to resolve the issue.

Comment: According to your code I hope that the QTableWidget are overlapping, is that the real case or do you use layouts to place them in different positions?

Comment: I cannot help you with the problem you have. But I have three other observations: 
1) do not use old Qt4 style of connections. Use Qt5 style instead.
2) You are memory-leaking the menus. You create them but never delete them.
3) You probably should check whether QModelIndex indices are valid before showing the menu for them. (well, you do not use the indices at all - why?)

Comment: Btw. have you tried to set breakpoints to the slots? Do they get called at all?

Comment: @eyllanesc The QTableWidgets are not overlapping and are placed in different locations within the view. Judging from your comment I have got something wrong, but I don't know what!

Comment: @V.K. The code works fine in debug, so breakpoints won't work - and as far as I can tell they do get called.

Comment: @V.K. 1) I only know the Qt4 style of connection - I'll look up Qt5 version. 2) The snippet is memory leaking, I have already fixed this in the actual code. 3) You are quite right that code is redundant - it is left over from when I was trying something. Apologies.

Comment: @Fergus Crawford - if you cannot set breakpoints, then you can use qDebug() << ... to write out some text to know that these slots are called.

Comment: @V.K. I can confirm that the slots are called correctly but that the menu->popup does not pop up a menu. I assume it is because I have fundamentally got something wrong in the use of the custom / context menu and how it should work with multiple tables... I just don't know what!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to make it work although I still do not understand why my code failed.

The way to make it work was to swap out the following:

```
menuNameOut->popup(pTableW_EmuNameOut->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
menuNameIn->popup(pTableW_EmuNameIn->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
menuParam->popup(pTableW_Param->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
```

for:

```
menuNameOut->exec(QCursor::pos());
menuNameIn->exec(QCursor::pos());
menuParam->exec(QCursor::pos());
```